# Is usage of "leverage" as a verb in "Leverage competencies to the value chains of other existing businesses" correct?

Tags: grammar, word-usage

"Leverage competencies to the value chains of other existing businesses"

In the above statement, is the word "leverage" used as a verb? If not, then which form is it? Are there any grammatical errors in the statement?

Is it grammatically correct/better to state, "Leverage competencies for the value chains of other existing businesses"? If not, then how best to convey the intended message using "leverage"?

leverage (verb) : use (something) to maximum advantage
(Oxford dictionary)

Comment: What is the intended message?

Comment: The person who coined "leverage" as a verb should IMO be banished to the very end of a lever long enough to move the world. Permanently.

Comment: Intended message: Using competencies in one area to create competencies in another area and in the process extracting some more benefit out of the existing competencies.

Comment: I worked in business for 40 years, have an MBA, and frankly I have never understood what sentences like this mean. Some of the problems I have with it are: "leverage" is a noun, not a verb; whose competencies; what specifically is a "value chain"?

Comment: It doesn't matter if the aforementioned definition is the only one or not, as long as it's one of the definitions of the word leverage. And imo, "leverage (use to max advantage) competencies (i.e. something) for the value chain...." fits with the definition instead of "leverage competencies to...", as you can use something for something (say, building) but not use something to building.

Comment: If you accept ”leverage" as a verb then it lends itself to, for instance, "leverage competencies…”. No, “leverage competencies to..." doesn’t work but “… in order to..." would be fine.

The example looks like two fragments squashed into a third, making anything else dodgy.

Comment: A computer guru of my acquaintance (from a world were verbs are used as nouns all the time) liked to say "There is no noun that can't be verbed." OTOH, I knew a lawyer who routinely, and scowlingly, replaced "Please contact me" with "Please be in touch."  "Leverage" is a term of art in Corpspeak. If it saves space and delivers the payload, it's fine. Just be sure you're writing for an audience that appreciates the usage.

Comment: One often sees leverage [direct object] but "leverage competencies to or for value chains" is very awkward, to say the least. [...] "to use these competences in the value chains of other businesses".

Comment: @CharlE My main problem with the verb "to leverage" (apart from its fundamental awfulness) is that it suffers from Humtpy Dumptyism (Lewis Carroll had Humpty Dumpty say, in Through the Looking Glass, "When I use a word it means exactly what I want it to mean  no more, no less"). Anytime I encounter any part of the verb 'to leverage' used in anything but the context of the debt load of a large corporation (where it is a genuine technical term with a tight description) I have a strong tendency to ignore not just the sentence containing it but the whole passage or speech.

Comment: The usage is not as strict as suggested by other commenters. [Cambridge](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/leverage) says "to use something that you already have in order to achieve something new or better:"

Answer (score 2):

The usage of "leverage" in the phrase quoted by you is correct. It has been used in exactly the same sense that you have stated.

The usage of "to" is slightly nonstandard, but it's not wrong. I've seen such usage in scientific journals as well.

The writer probably means that competencies acquired for a purpose can be mapped to the value chain of other businesses. For example, I might acquire a master's degree in Earth Science. However, I might use the same skill sets and knowledge as the Editor of an Earth Science magazine instead of pursuing a career in mainstream Earth Science.

Answer (score 0):

It depends on how you use the content.  Example....way to capitalize on your position is by leveraging it. In other words, to leverage (verb) your leverage (noun).

It takes a verb, to lever, that has become a noun, leverage, and twists the word into another verb even though it ends with the noun-defining ending –age.

Lever = (Verb)  - Leverage = (Noun)

By adding the suffix (age), it becomes a noun.

Advance = (Verb)  - Advantage = (Noun)

It's the same concept as they say if you change an ingredient on a recipe, that becomes a new recipe.

Answer (score -1):

The first sentence is more grammatically correct than the second.

If you are to use the preposition "for," better include the reason for leveraging competencies as "for" is "used to indicate why something is done".

See http://learnersdictionary.com/definition/for

Hope this helps.

Comment: “For does not always explain a reason, although it can do (“a present for your birthday”). It can also define the recipient (eg “a present for you” or the example in the question).

Answer (score -1):

**It is *not* a verb**, despite any of the American references.

'Leverage' is the advantage gained by the use of a lever. The noun comes by adding the suffix *-age* to the verb 'lever'.

Add *-age* to the verb 'spill' and you get the noun 'spillage'.

Add *-age* to the verb 'advance' and you get the noun 'advantage'.

The suffix *-age* transforms these verbs into nouns.  That's what it's for.

You can't add *-age* to 'lever' and pretend that it's a verb as well.

If 'leverage' was a verb you could create 'leverageage' which shows the error.

Comment: The Oxford English Dictionary says that you're wrong, and far be it from me to contradict their scholarship in this matter.

Answer (score -2):

Leverage is not a verb nor should it be used as one. The English language is rich enough to  contain plenty of verbs to indicate the movement required. Manipulate, twist, manoeuvre, move, lever, push will all fill the need.

Comment: "Leverage" as a verb is established. [See MW](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/leverage).  Also [Cambridge](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/leverage). Also [OALD](https://www.oxfordlearnersdictionaries.com/definition/english/leverage_2) We don't do opinion here.

Comment: BTW, I see you're new here. Welcome to ELU--do give some time to the [tour] if you haven't yet. Cheers!

Comment: @Conrado Thank you for the invite to coln...I have been fielding so much stuff on the review queue that I often forget being polite. We need more older users here welcoming the  noobies. I used to do that, a long time ago...early guidance may help avoid much of the fluff and stuff...

Comment: @Cascabel You're welcome, I'm glad I can be helpful that way--I think it's part of my job here, and can complement your more concise and "meaty" comments. Cheers!